# Adding Cells to existing UICollectionView (mutating method sent to immutable object)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am trying to find a way to add cells to a collection and it keeps giving me the "mutating method sent to immutable object" error. I do not know why. Posted below is the code I am working with.

```
    self.artistArray = [responseObject objectForKey:@"data"];
    self.paginationArray = [responseObject objectForKey:@"pagination"];
    //NSLog(@"%@", self.paginationArray);

    if(self.firstRequest){
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
        self.firstRequest = FALSE;
    }
    else{
        NSArray *newData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"otherData", nil];

        [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
            int resultsSize = [self.artistArray count]; //data is the previous array of data
            [self.artistArray addObjectsFromArray:newData];
            NSMutableArray *arrayWithIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];

            for (int i = resultsSize; i < resultsSize + newData.count; i++) {
                [arrayWithIndexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i
                                                                  inSection:0]];
            }
            [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:arrayWithIndexPaths];
        } completion:nil];

    }
```

If you guys have any questions let me know and I will try my best to answer you.

Comment: Please, show **artistArray** property declaration string

Comment: @Brain89 the delcaration is : 'self.artistArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];' in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose

```
[responseObject objectForKey:@"data"];
```

returns immutable object. Just add mutableCopy

```
[[responseObject objectForKey:@"data"] mutableCopy];
```

Or you can clear array and add new objects instead of strong assignment

```
[self.artistArray removeAllObjects];
[self.artistArray addObjectsFromArray:[responseObject objectForKey:@"data"]];
```

**UPD**

If you try to add new cells you should synchronize your datasource and collection cells. So try this

```
self.paginationArray = [responseObject objectForKey:@"pagination"];
if(self.firstRequest){
    [self.artistArray removeAllObjects];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
    self.firstRequest = FALSE;
}
else {
    NSArray *newData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"otherData", nil];

    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        int resultsSize = [self.artistArray count]; //data is the previous array of data
        [self.artistArray addObjectsFromArray:newData];
        [self.artistArray addObjectsFromArray:[responseObject objectForKey:@"data"]];
        NSMutableArray *arrayWithIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i = resultsSize; i < resultsSize + newData.count; i++) {
            [arrayWithIndexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i
                                                              inSection:0]];
        }
        [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:arrayWithIndexPaths];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: That part worked thanks. Im getting some other error now. An EXC_BAD_ACCESS for the performBatchUpdates. 

But your answer corrected the first problem!